# "Error: Cannot find module 'pkginfo'" - node js app deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm getting the following error when attempting to deploy my node.js app to Heroku for the first time:

Application loaded using the "production" environment configuration
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823904+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823906+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823900+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'pkginfo'
2014-08-28T01:02:56.817349+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823915+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823908+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823910+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823912+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/index.js:440:1)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823913+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.814921+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-08-28T01:02:56.838954+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
2014-08-28T01:02:56.815953+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823920+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.823917+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-08-28T01:02:56.815545+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340

I've followed all of the steps from Heroku's website for deploying node, but have been stuck on fixing this above error. I can successfully do "foreman start" on my local computer. At first, after doing "foreman start", I got the same error "Cannot find module 'pkginfo', so i installed pkginfo on my local computer and then foreman start worked and i could launch my app on localhost:5000 without any problems. However, still stuck on fixing this error on Heroku's server. Any help?

Thanks!
Jason

Comment: do you have the app in your node_modules folder?

Comment: where in the node_modules folder should my app be? I see the following in node_modules folder:

body-parser,
bower,
compression,
connect-flash,
connect-mongo,
consolidate,
cookie-parser,
cool-ascii-faces,
eventemitter3,
express,
express-session,
forever,
glob,
grunt-cli,
helmet,
lodash,
method-override,
mongoose,
morgan,
passport,
passport-facebook,
passport-google-oauth,
passport-linkedin,
passport-local,
passport-twitter,
swig

Comment: I meant to say the module 'pkginfo'

Comment: alright, go to the node command line and install the module `npm install pkginfo`. Make sure you `cd`ed into the node_modules folder of you app

Comment: ok i'll try that now. One sec. Thanks!

Comment: ok now pkginfo is in node_modules. I'm going to deploy to heroku again now

Comment: ok i can now access http://sheltered-forest-9677.herokuapp.com/ without the pkginfo error! Thanks for your help! Do you want to add this answer below so i can mark yours as the solution?

Comment: One sec, I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is install the package in your production environment

1.Go into your main app directory

`cd appDirectory`

2.Install the module

`npm install pkginfo`

3.Re-deploy